# Python: testing a method was called inside another method

Tags: python, unit-testing

Here is my class method:

```
def create(self, document=None):
    resp = self.db.document(None).post(params=document)

    if not resp.ok:
        logging.exception("Unknown response from Cloudant: %d" % resp.status_code)
        raise SystemError("Error creating document")

    if resp.ok and document.get("status") == "active":
        self.create_eda_document(resp.json().get("id"), document)

    return resp
```

And the test:

```
def test_create(self):
    self.klass.db = mock.MagicMock()
    self.klass.db.document = mock.MagicMock()
    post_mock = mock.MagicMock()
    d = {
        'ok': True,
        'id': '123',
        'rev': '1-bar'
    }
    resp_mock = mock.MagicMock(ok=True)
    resp_mock.__getitem__.side_effect = lambda name: d[name]
    post_mock.return_value = resp_mock
    post_mock.json.return_value = {"id": "123"}
    self.klass.db.document.return_value.post = post_mock
    self.klass.create_eda_document = mock.MagicMock(return_value={
        'ok': True,
        'id': '546',
        'rev': '1-baz'
    })

    resp = self.klass.create(
        document={
            'workflow': test_workflow(),
            'status': 'active',
            'name': 'Foo Bar',
            'account_id': 100,
            'created_at': party_like_its,
            'updated_at': party_like_its,
            'deleted_at': None
        }
    )

    print(resp)

    self.assertDictEqual(
        resp,
        {
            'ok': True,
            'id': '123',
            'rev': '1-bar'
        }
    )
    self.klass.create_eda_document.assert_called_once_with(
        '123',
        {
            'workflow': test_workflow(),
            'status': 'active',
            'name': 'Foo Bar',
            'account_id': 100,
            'created_at': party_like_its,
            'updated_at': party_like_its,
            'deleted_at': None
        }
    )
```

The final `self.klass.created_eda_document.assert_called_once_with` is failing because it actually isn't being called in the test. It's supposed to run because the document passed into the `create` method is "active", but the test says it's not. Not sure why it's not running

## Update

Here's my test code

```
def test_create(self):
    self.klass.db = mock.MagicMock()
    self.klass.db.document = mock.MagicMock()
    post_mock = mock.MagicMock(ok=True)
    post_mock.return_value = {
        'id': '123',
        'ok': True,
        'rev': '1-bar'
    }
    self.klass.db.document.return_value.post = post_mock

    resp = self.klass.create(
        document={
            'workflow': test_workflow(),
            'status': 'active',
            'name': 'Foo Bar',
            'account_id': 100,
            'created_at': party_like_its,
            'updated_at': party_like_its,
            'deleted_at': None
        }
    )

    self.assertDictEqual(
        resp,
        {
            'ok': True,
            'id': '123',
            'rev': '1-bar'
        }
    )
```

And here's the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmonsewicz/dev/autoresponders/tests/app/utils/test_workflows_cloudant.py", line 126, in test_create
    'deleted_at': None
  File "/Users/dmonsewicz/dev/autoresponders/app/utils/workflows_cloudant.py", line 40, in create
    if not resp.ok:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'ok'
```

Comment: You've mocked out the method that was supposed to call `create_eda_document`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to adjust my code so that everything is mocked out properly?

Comment: If you want to test `create`, don't mock it. Mock its inputs if you need to, but not the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to mock `resp.json()`:

```
post_mock = mock.MagicMock()
post_mock.json.return_value = {"id": '123'}
self.klass.db.return_value.post = post_mock
```

Second, you don't actually want to do this:

```
self.klass.create = mock.MagicMock(return_value={
     'ok': True,
     'id': '123',
     'rev': '1-bar'
})
```

Since now you've mocked out the `create` method, which is what is supposed to call `create_eda_document`.

Also, you need to mock `resp` differently. It needs to be a dict-like object that also has an `ok` attribute. I think the best way to do that is to subclass `dict`:

```
class fakedict(dict):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(fakedict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ok  = None
```

...

```
post_mock = mock.MagicMock()
d = {
    'ok': True,
    'id': '123',
    'rev': '1-bar'
}
resp_mock = fakedict(d)
resp_mock.ok = True
post_mock.return_value = resp_mock
```

Your test will still pass without this change, though, because `resp.ok` will end up still being a non-Falsey value.

Comment: Now when I run the `self.klass.create` the response coming back is `<MagicMock name='mock.document().post()' id='4463821200'>`

Comment: hmm... 1) Thanks so much for your help! 2) It's still failing with the same error. Let me update my question with the new code (including your help)

Comment: @dennismonsewicz I've fixed it somewhat. The problem is you're trying to treat resp like a `dict` with the `self.assertDictEqual` call, but it's not really a dict; normal dicts don't have an `ok` property.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Actually, does it really even make sense to test  `resp` in this case? You're mocking it anyway. To really test it, you'd need to say `self.assertEquals(resp, resp_mock)`, which seems a bit strange.

Comment: It doesn't. I am updating my question with the latest bit of code and the error I am receiving

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Ok, so you're not longer trying to test that `create_eda_document` got called?

Comment: I eliminated it just to get the test to pass, but I will be adding it back in